# How to compare 2 numeric columes in the file/files

Tags: bash, awk

I have following file with 3 columns. I can put the columns in 2 separate files if required.

```
user1--6050--50000
user2--50--50000
user3--5550--50000
user4--60000--50000
user5--70000--50000
user6--1--50000
```

So the above values are second colume representing usage of users. And the 3rd column represents the quota available.
So I want compare column2 with column3 and if the value of column2 is exceeding column3 then Report the respective user.
In this case the user5 should be reported as 70000 is greater than 50000

How do we achieve this?

Awk only has compare (=) Parameter. So any other Suggestion please?

Comment: `Awk only has compare (=) Parameter`. What ? `awk -F"--" '$2>$3{print $1}'` ?

Comment: the statement made by me purely based on my limited knowledge of awk .....so Excuse me .I think the one liner by you sums up all. Works well. Thanks.

Comment: @User112638726 you should post that as an answer so the OP can accept it and move on before he starts asking how to change the oil in his car.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
   my ( $user, $alloc, $quota ) = ( m/^(\w+)--(\d+)--(\d+)/ );
   print $user,"\n" if $alloc > $quota;
}

__DATA__
user1--6050--50000
user2--50--50000
user3--5550--50000
user4--60000--50000
user5--70000--50000
user6--1--50000
```

Prints:

```
user4
user5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `cat /tmp/log`;do 
val1=`echo $i | cut -d- -f3`
val2=`echo $i | cut -d- -f5` 
[[ $val1 -gt $val2 ]] && echo ${i%%-*}
done
```